# Using GPUImage live video filter in basic project results in plain white screen

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have just integrated `GPUImage` in a brand new project, and have added the required libraries per the instructions in the [Github](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) page. I have made a `strong` property of`GPUImageVideoCamera` and in `viewDidLoad`, I instantiate it as such:

```
self.videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

**Edit**: Complete code in the project:

```
@interface ViewController () <GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    GPUImagePixellatePositionFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImagePixellatePositionFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
    [customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
}

@end
```

However, all I am getting is a white screen without any errors or warnings, and was wondering what I am doing incorrectly... thanks!

Comment: This is running on a device, not the Simulator? You're sure the view is visible?

Comment: Thanks for responding @BradLarson - yes, this is running on my iPhone 5. I can post the entire project if helpful.

Comment: @BradLarson posted the entire project seen in `ViewController.m`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I ran into the same problem and found a fix. It seems really stupid, but for me I just made the videoCamera a property and it began to work, i.e:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImageVideoCamera *camera;

@end

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.camera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    //etc.
}
```